# How can I highlight tags in Emacs buffers?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `find-tag` and `kill-this-buffer` to navigate through Fortran 90 code with the help of key bindings like

```
(global-set-key [(control return)] 'find-tag ) ;
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'kill-this-buffer) ;
```

This provides a relative smooth experience in code browsing. Unfortunately not all of my tags have the same highlighting. So I ended up in adding targets manually to font-lock-keywords with expressions like

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords 'f90-mode
              '(
                ("\\(my_function\\)" 1 font-lock-function-name-face t )
                ))))
```

in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Is there a solution to highlight every name, which is listed in the `TAGS` file, if it occurs in a buffer, which is in f90-mode?

I am most interested in a solution for `f90-mode`, but of course a general solution would be even better.

Comment: Edited to address the remarks from @Drew in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, but it is not too clear what you mean by "such highlighting" and especially "based on the contents of the TAGS file".

- *"Such highlighting"* -- Font-lock highlighting is for the viewing buffer, in this case a buffer in `f90-mode`.  So you really do need to add the font-locking for that mode, in any case.  This is independent of how you get into the mode (from visiting `TAGS` or in some other way).
- *"Based on the contents of the TAGS file"* -- Those contents will tell you what names are defined (and where), but nothing more.

But perhaps you are saying that you get the name `my_function` from the `TAGS` file, and that you want to font-lock (in `f90-mode`) *every name* listed in `TAGS` as being defined.  If that is the case then yes, you could parse `TAGS` to get a list of defined names, and add each of them to `font-lock-keywords` for `f90-mode`.  You can use `(tags-completion-table)` to get the list of tags (defined names) in `TAGS`.

Just use `mapatoms` to iterate over the obarray returned by `(tags-completion-table)`.  The function argument would add a `font-lock-keywords` entry for the symbol.  Something like this (untested):

```
(defun foo ()
  (require 'etags)
  (let ((defined-symbs  (tags-completion-table)))
    (mapatoms (lambda (symb)
                (font-lock-add-keywords
                  'f90-mode `((,(format "\\(%s\\)" symb)
                              1 font-lock-function-name-face t)))))))
```

But be aware that (a) that will take a while to execute and (b) that adds ***every*** symbol defined in your `TAGS` table, so it will become font-locked in `f90-mode`.  Is that really what you want?  If your `TAGS` table is specifically created from (only) Fortran files, then that might make sense; otherwise, maybe not.

Because it can take a while, you would invoke `foo` only once, not each time you enter `f90-mode`.  You could do that again after you update your `TAGS` file, to pick up any changes.  If (b) is a consideration, then you can perhaps add some filtering test to the function arg to `mapatoms`, so that only certain symbols get font-locked.

Anyway, perhaps this will get you started. HTH.

Comment: Yes, you definitely understood my question. Thanks for great insights.